# Как исключить повторения в выводе данных? JS JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

У меня есть json файл, который содержит массив с объектами и их свойствами. Нужно вывести определенную иерархию (Город - Район - Улица - Житель). Путем перебор объектов я получил эти данные, но у меня возникла следующая проблема. Как мне исключить повторение этих данных и выводить жителей строго по иерархии, а не все данные отдельно? Есть ли какой способ проверки предыдущих значений?

[image: Иерархия данных]

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Михаил",
"city_id": 1,
"groups": [
  {
    "type": "city",
    "name": "Москва г."
  },
  {
    "type": "district",
    "name": "Пресненский р-н"
  },
  {
    "type": "street",
    "name": "Гашека ул."
  }
]
```

}

[image: Данные из вывода]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройдитесь в цикле по массиву и на его основе создайте объект типа:

```
{
  город1: {
     район1: {
       улица1: {
         id_жителя1: данные_жителя1,
         id_жителя2: данные_жителя2,
         id_жителя3: данные_жителя3
       },
       улица2: {
         id_жителя4: данные_жителя4,
         id_жителя5: данные_жителя5
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Для каждого элемента массива вы смотрите, есть ли в объекте такой город. Нет, создаете. Потом, есть ли в объекте города такой район. Нет, создаете...

Comment: Можешь помочь пожалуйста? Как составить такое условие, чтобы он проверял и создавал? Понимаю логику, но без понятия как такое сделать.